# download canvas to images using loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to place text on canvas and download it as image in foreach loop.
text contains different fonts. i want to download 230 such images.

Code :

```
<div id="divFontPreview">
    <ul id="ulFonts">
        <li><a href="#" title="Times" new="" roman="" id="Times" style="font-family: Times New Roman">
        Times New Roman</a></li><li><a href="#" title="ABeeZee" id="ABeeZee" style="font-family: ABeeZee">
        ABeeZee</a></li><li><a href="#" title="Abel" id="Abel" style="font-family: Abel">Abel</a></li><li>
        <a href="#" title="Abril" fatface="" id="Abril" style="font-family: Abril Fatface">Abril
        Fatface</a></li><li><a href="#" title="Aclonica" id="Aclonica" style="font-family: Aclonica">
        Aclonica</a></li><li><a href="#" title="Acme" id="Acme" style="font-family: Acme">Acme</a></li><li>
        <a href="#" title="Action" man="" id="Action" style="font-family: Action Man">Action
        Man</a></li><li><a href="#" title="Actor" id="Actor" style="font-family: Actor">Actor</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <canvas id="fonts" width="293" height="40" style="position: relative; border: solid;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Script :

```
$('#btnStart').click(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
                $('#divFontPreview').find('a').each(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var text = $(this).text().trim();
                    var c = document.getElementById("fonts");
                    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
                    ctx.font = "20px " + text;
                    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 28);
                    var dt = c.toDataURL("image/png");
                    dt = dt.replace('data:image/png;base64', 'data:application/octet-stream;base64');
                    $(this).attr('download', text + '.png');
                    $(this).attr('href', dt);
                });
              }, 500);
     });
```

Code runs without any error but no files is getting download. If i remove foreach loop and add event to each `anchor` tag it gets downloaded.

Comment: You're making the client computer do a lot of work and a lot of waiting. Instead, you might create your font-images in pre-production and combine them in a spritesheet.  Send the spritesheet to the client and let the client pull each font off the spritesheet.

Comment: @markE : This is a dummy application, i am going to do exactly what you have mentioned. This code run only once just to create images of all the fonts.